# Parameterizing IN clause in PowerQuery SQL query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, power-query

I've seen [examples](https://blog.oraylis.de/2013/05/using-dynamic-parameter-values-in-power-query-queries/) (and coded one) that parameterize a PowerQuery SQL statement with values read from cells in the spreadsheet'a table.  But these always deal with simple logical conditionals like `myField = <parameter>`.  I want to parameterize a IN clause (`myField IN <values>`), where an arbitrary number of `values` are read from an Excel table (also in the same file).  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ugly, but it seems to work.

1. create PQ query to capture single column 'parameterValue' table of desired parameter values
2. add dummy column and group all rows by dummy
3. use Text.Combine to create parameter list and remove other columns
4. drill down to cell value
5. create desired sql query without IN clause (use 'select top 1...' for efficiency)
6. using Advanced Editor, modify sql query delete 'top 1' and accept query from step 1 as IN parameter

query1:

```
let
    source = *yourData*,
    addDummy = Table.AddColumn(source, "Custom", each 1),
    group = Table.Group(addDummy, {"Custom"}, {{"Count", each _, type table}}),
    string = Table.AddColumn(group, "queryString", each Text.Combine([Count][parameterValue],"','")),
    removeOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(string,{"queryString"}),
    queryString = removeOtherColumns{0}[queryString]
in
    queryString
```

then

query2:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("*serverName*", "*dbName*", [Query=
Text.Replace("
select * from x
where parameterValue in('" & query1 & ")", ")", "')" )
])
in 
Source
```

Comment: I am getting the infamous __Formula.Firewall__ error on query2. Step Sep 'Source' references other queries or steps...

Comment: I got around this issue by using some macro code to generate the SQL as a string. Then update the query's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Ken Puls has a good write up about using a parameter table with Power Query in his blog here: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/

Executive summary: Build a table for the parameters, write a function to read a specified parameter, use the function in the M code to dynamically apply the desired parameter.

You may need to extend this approach to build your SQL statement as a string.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I already know how to get single parameters (I even included a link to an example).  And yes, I did see the comment about `WHERE IN`.  That's still not what I'm asking about.  What I want to do is read an array of values from a table.

Answer (score 0):

I would first build a Power Query e.g. "Values" to read in the Excel Table rows. I would set the Load To = Connection Only.

Then in the main SQL-based Query I would Merge with that new "Values" query, and set the Join Kind = Inner.